# How to change Home / End behaviour on Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I want to change the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys to work like Windows/Linux.

CHANGE:

<kbd>Home</kbd> to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.   // Beginning of the line

<kbd>End</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.  // End of the line

I tried using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app known as KeyRemap4MacBook. But it doesn't work on Yosemite while I write code on editors like Sublime Text, PhpStorm, WebStorm, etc.

I also did create a `DefaultKeyBindings.dict` file (with proper settings) inside `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and `OSX/Library/KeyBindings/`.

So, is there a way to remap the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys for glabally on my mac. I could use Terminal command too.
I don't want an app for that.

Answer (score 3):

You might have to change the custom settings in the Terminal app. But it's quite straight forward. See here: http://fdiv.net/2007/05/12/keybindings-in-macosx-terminal-app

I also changed it for my Sublime Text 2:

```
   { "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol"} },
   { "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol"} },
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this behavior using Karabiner (I know you  tried already, but please read). I use it extensively on Yosemite (10.10.2)

Optional (can't remember if is 100% necessary), but follow just in case:

- Add `Karabiner_AXNotifier.app` on System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy (tab or horizontal menu on top) > Accessibility (left column)

Then:

1. Open Karabiner preferences and go to the ‘Misc & Uninstall’ tab.
2. Click the ‘Open private.xml’ button (under ‘Custom Settings’)
3. Add this content to private.xml (create the file if doesn't exist):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
         <name>Fix Home/End</name>
         <appendix>(Home/End move to beg/end of line, Ctl/Cmd+Home/End move to beg/end of page)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.app_firefox_fix_home_end</identifier>
         <only>FIREFOX, THUNDERBIRD</only>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_HOME, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,   ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_HOME, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,   ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_END,  MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_END,  MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_HOME, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ FROMKEYCODE_END, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
4. Return to the ‘Change Key’ tab.
5. Click the ‘Reload XML’ button.
6. Search for ‘System-wide’ in the search box and check the ‘Fix Home/End System-wide’ (I named it this way to make it easier for you to activate)
7. Try the Home/End keys.

Comment: Thanks. I will try when i get to office after 10 days. I don't have full keyboard currently.

Comment: The solution you found is from OS X Lion. Yosemite is very different. I open bounty again and give you if it is working. Sorry i am agnostic.